# Unsupported type error durring sending email to Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem saving data (name, surname, email) to FireStore database. The authorization is working great - new users are adding. But then I want to save this 3 variables from AndroidStudio's EditText type as a new document of Firebase.
But then suddenly error in console appears:

```
Process: com.example.poduszkowoapp, PID: 7276
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText (found in field Email)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.UserData$ParseContext.createError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:293)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:405)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:254)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseMap(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:274)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:230)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseSetData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:75)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:172)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:152)
        at com.example.poduszkowoapp.RegisterActivity$1$2.onComplete(RegisterActivity.java:90)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The code of this section in Register Acitivity where problems appears:

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmail.getText().toString(),txtPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                userMap.put("Name", txtName);
                                userMap.put("Surname", txtSurname);
                                userMap.put("Email", txtEmail);
                                fStore.collection("users").document(userID).set(userMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            if(e instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "This email address is already taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are passing instances of Android views to Firestore:

```
Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("Name", txtName);
userMap.put("Surname", txtSurname);
userMap.put("Email", txtEmail);
```

If `txtEmail` and others are Android view objects, this isn't going to work at all.  Firestore doesn't know anything about Android views.  You have to write code to extract the string values out of the widgets, and pass those strings to Firestore.  For example, to get a string out of an EditText:

```
userMap.put("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your map be:

```
Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("Name", txtName.getText().toString());
userMap.put("Surname", txtSurname.getText().toString());
userMap.put("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
```

You were writing your EditText type to firestore instead of the text from it.